# What's a word for "newcomer to politics"?

Tags: american-english

Incumbent means someone who currently holds office.  Is there a word that describes someone who is completely new to politics, like "rookie" does for sports.  I feel like "rookie" doesn't fit well with political office, though.

Comment: Rookie or Amateur works here

Comment: Does this politician show great potential? If yes, he may be called a **"rising politician".**

Comment: or a "rising figure within the Political Class".

Answer (score 2):

In American English "freshman" is common, especially when discussing legislators.

> [freshman](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/freshman?s=t): lacking seniority or experience; junior:

Comment: Odd to see "freshman" defined as "junior."

Answer (score 1):

***fledgling***

> *n.* a young or inexperienced person.
>
> *adj.* new and untried or inexperienced.
>
> *Lamont said yesterday: "He is a fledgling politician and a fledgling journalist and he will have learn you do not damage people's reputations that have been hard won.*
>
> [American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Fledgling)

***newbie***

> : a person who has recently started a particular activity.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/newbie)

Answer (score 0):

> [**neophyte**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neophyte) : a person who has just started learning or doing something; : a person who has recently joined a religious group

The "religious" group being other politicians.

Answer (score 0):

## [Amateur](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/amateur)

> <sub>[disapproving]</sub>
>
> someone who does not have much ​skill in what they do
>
> *"I won't be giving them any more ​work - they're a ​bunch of amateurs."*

## [Rookie](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rookie)

> a person who has just started a job or activity and has little experience

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rookie%20politician,amateur%20politician) shows that "amateur politician" was used more than "rookie politician" and it peaked in usage in the 1940s.

Both, ["amateur politician"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22amateur%20politician%22) and ["rookie politician"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rookie%20politician%22) have quite a lot of search results on Google to say that it's a common usage. There are results showing books, news, etc containing these words.

Btw, if the politician shows good potential, he may be referred to as a "rising politician".

## [Rising](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rising)

> increasing in rank, status, or reputation: ***"a rising young politician."***